# Unable to sent message into apache qpid jms 6.0.5 queue

Tags: java, apache, jms, qpid

I am using apache qpid jms 6.0.5 server and getting below exception. Any suggestion or help ...

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.qpid.AMQProtocolException:
>   Protocol: 0.0 is required by the broker but is not currently supported
>   by this client library implementation [error code 543: client
>   unsupported protocol]     at
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.initDelegate(AMQConnection.java:679)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.makeConnection(AMQConnection.java:568)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.(AMQConnection.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.(AMQConnection.java:294)
>     at org.apache.qpid.example.ListSender.main(ListSender.java:47) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_0_0  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.initDelegate(AMQConnection.java:663)
>     ... 4 more

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What version of the Qpid Client library are you using?

Comment: I am using qpid version 6.0.5. It's working after remove queue at specified port initially through admin panel.